# Convert clustered PK index to nonclustered on system versioned table

Tags: sql-server

I have a large system versioned table (1b+ rows) whose primary key index I naively allowed to be clustered. I would like to drop it and recreate it as a nonclustered index. Will it suffice to set system versioning OFF, drop/create the index, then turn system versioning ON?

Comment: You are mixing in the word index and primary key a little loosely. By default, when you create a primary key a clustered index will be automatically created on that key if a clustered index doesn't already exist. Are you not planning on having a clustered index at all?

Comment: if you drop PK; then are you planning on accepting null values in that column. Sql server will not move your data esp as right now its organized on disk physically. BUT any new rows you insert will be randomly throw where ever (i.e. on heap) and over time your querying on this table WILL BECOME slow. Keep in mind NCI will also cost you memory to create and maintain. Dont forget to update stats on such a big table periodically (depending on your no of DMLs)

Comment: @scsimon No, there will be a different clustered index composed of actual search keys. The current index is just the auto-incrementing row id. Useful as a foreign key, but not much else.

Comment: @junketsu The column specified for the index is still declared IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, so I think it will always have the properties I desire. The index containing it just won't be clustered.

Comment: So you have a surrogate key. What is it’s purpose? If it can be a FK for another table then it’s likely a good candidate for a PK of this table. But hey it’s your design. I voted to move this to DBA.stackexchange